# Custom camera view overlay size problems when app rotates

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera

I am using a custom camera view overlay in Swift 3. When I move the camera from landscape to portrait, it cuts the camera view size down. Is there a way to check the device orientation and change the frame bounds? Right now the line of code I'm using is

`previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds`

Answer (score 2):

You got several options for this. The main idea is to get a function to be called whenever there is a change in the view.

**Option 1, iOS8+**

> As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated. Instead, rotations are treated as a change in the size of the view controller’s view and are therefore reported using the viewWillTransition(to:with:) method. When the interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view controller hierarchy.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    var previewLayer:CALayer?

    if let layer = previewLayer {
        layer.frame = self.view.bounds //or:
        layer.frame.size = size //If coordinates is (x:0,y:0) you only need to update the size, and that is provided through the function
    }
}
```

**Option 2, iOS 6 & 7**

> In iOS 6 and iOS 7, your app supports the interface orientations defined in your app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override the supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of supported orientations. Typically, the system calls this method only on the root view controller of the window or a view controller presented to fill the entire screen; child view controllers use the portion of the window provided for them by their parent view controller and no longer participate directly in decisions about what rotations are supported. The intersection of the app's orientation mask and the view controller's orientation mask is used to determine which orientations a view controller can be rotated into.
>
> When a rotation occurs for a visible view controller, the willRotate(to:duration:), willAnimateRotation(to:duration:), and didRotate(from:) methods are called during the rotation. The viewWillLayoutSubviews() method is also called after the view is resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews() method is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the device orientation.

When the orientation changes this method will be called and therefor you can update previewLayer.frame there.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var previewLayer:CALayer?

    if let layer = previewLayer {
    layer.frame = self.view.bounds
    }
}
```

or

```
override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {
var previewLayer:CALayer?
if let layer = previewLayer {
layer.frame = self.view.bounds
}
}
```

Comment: previewLayer.frame.size = size worked perfect!! Thanks so much